# Error implementing flask_images with python 3.7.3

Tags: python, html, flask

I am having issues referencing flask_images on jinja2 template... Implementation works on python 2.7 and on img tag () and div (as background image) but doesnt work on python 3.7.3 when implemented on jinja2 template with div tag (as background-image)

```
<div class="background" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,100) 100%), url({{ resized_img_src(all_static_images[3], width=700, height=312, quality=90) }})"></div>
```

IT WORKS PERFECTLY WITH THE CODE BELOW

```
<img src='{{ resized_img_src(all_static_images[3], width=700, height=312, quality=90) }}'>
```

Comment: WHAT CODE BELOW? There's no need to shout and you haven't included the code

Comment: IT DOESNT WORK ON THIS

<div class="background" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,100) 100%), url({{ resized_img_src(all_static_images[3], width=700, height=312, quality=90) }})"></div>

IT WORKS PERFECTLY WITH THE CODE BELOW

<img src='{{ resized_img_src(all_static_images[3], width=700, height=312, quality=90) }}'>

Comment: This is silly. [edit] your question to get the code into the main post. You can preview your post before you actually submit it simply by scrolling down from the editor.

Comment: Right, stop editing. I will try fix it.

Comment: Thanks .... I am here waiting for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the question..

python flask_image is rendered on html by jinja2 template with single quote.. This was making it not unrecognized ...

Simply put,

I replaced single quote (') with (%27) using jinja in python flask

Code Example

```
<div class="background" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,100) 100%), url({{ resized_img_src(all_static_images[3], width=700, height=312, quality=90) | replace("'","%27") }})"></div>
```